# Whatsapp Backup

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am using whatsapp in HTC Desire VC (CDMA-GSM Dual Sim Phone). It has internal space of 100MB only and unfortunately my phone no longer supporting external SD card. I want to take backup of my chat history but every time click on backup chats it shows that "please insert an SD Card". I also tried to back up my data via Google Drive but it shows same message. I also tried to email chat but same problem.

I don't know what to do backup my chat history.

Is it possible to take backup of chat history online which no requires SD card or any other external drives.

Please tell me what to do. 
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp app **automatically** takes a back up of your chat history, **locally**. So your phone does not HAVE TO have an external SD-card.

Below is the quote from official WhatsApp [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921) regarding the back up.

> Local backups will run automatically every day at 2am and save your
>   database in a file on the phone itself.

You can use any **[File manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20manager%20or%20file%20explorer&c=apps)** to check/verify this local back up.
Just go to your **Internal Storage->WhatsApp->Databases**

At this location you should see file such as `msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt8`

This is the back up of your chat history. **Your phone will store up to the last 7 days worth of local backup files**

If you want to **restore** this back up (in case you switched phone or uninstalled WhatsApp), you may refer to the [restore section](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921#restore) of FAQ of WhatsApp and follow the instructions there to restore your chat history.